# Ubuntu 16.04: How is the bonding kernel module gettting loaded automatically?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, network-interface

I recently set up an Ubuntu 16.04 system with a bonded ethernet configuration.  Previously, it appears that to get this to work the bonding module needed to be included in `/etc/modules` or `/etc/modules.d`.  This is documented here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding

However, on the Ubuntu 16.04 system I just set up, I didn't doing anything to force the loading of the bonding kernel module (e.g. no entry in `/etc/modules`) and yet the bonding kernel module is loaded and the bonded port is working as advertised.

I've been trying to figure out what is triggering this module load and can't find it.  As far as I can tell, Canonical did not get it together to switch to systemd-networkd for the 16.04 release, so there is no systemd magic at work as far as I can tell..  Also no `udev` rules are defined.

Now the whole thing is really bothering me (particularly since not explicitly loading the module in 14.04 would not have worked), so asking on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetworkManager gained support for bonding recently. I doubt it expects you to load the module manually.

There's a minority of tutorials that don't tell you to load the module, so I wonder about the ifenslave script... hah.

From the Debian 8 package, file ifenslave.pre-up:

```
add_master()
{
    # Return if $BOND_MASTER is already a bonding interface.
    [ -f "/sys/class/net/$BOND_MASTER/bonding/slaves" ] && return

    # If the bonding module is not yet loaded, load it.
    if [ ! -r /sys/class/net/bonding_masters ]; then
        modprobe -q bonding
    fi
```